# protocol and domain are removed from Hyperlinks

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

I have some php code that uses tinymce to enter a message that is then emailed using the php mail function. The email is successfully sent.

The problem is on the live server (RHEL 7.2) any hyperlink that is part of the message has its protocol (http://) and domain (www.example.net) removed and replaced with a relative path. 
   `../../client_services/media/pdfs/`

On my dev server (Centos 6) the email is sent and the hyperlinks retain the protocol and domain as follows 
    `http://www.example.net/client_services/media/pdfs/`

Both server are using the same version of tinymce.min.js (4.1.7)

The live server uses php version version 5.4.16-42

The dev server uses php version 5.3.3-49

I find no other differences. The code for the page is the same on both servers.

Is this problem related to the newer php version, or is something else altering the hyperlinks, like a php.ini configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure you have `relative_urls : false, remove_script_host : false` in your `tinymce.init()` params

Comment: Excellent help Joe. That solved my problem. I'm puzzled why the dev sever did not require these parameters.